# Getting request from stripe multiple times to my bot server

Tags: stripe-payments, chatbot, whatsapp, stripe-payment-intent

I have created a whatsapp bot and integrated stripe payment in my bot. After ordering items I will get a payment link from stripe to do the payment. After payment is completed stripe will send a request to my server (payment callback) endpoint, then I will get a thank you message. So now when ever after the payment from stripe the payment callback request is repeqadly coming. It should hit my bot endpoint only once for after every payment. I dont know why it is hitting repeatdly can someone help me with this issur?

I used test account of stripe and added my server url in stripe account webhook and subscribed to invoice_successful and invoice_failed events.  What Im expecting is when ever i made a payment, the request from stripe should only hit once and i should get the thank you message only once.

Comment: For every payment changes, it should only send one event provided if your server acknowledges with 200 status code in the response. If your server doesn't respond 200, Stripe will [retry](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic) sending the events.

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: You can check in Webhook [page](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks) in the Dashboard > Your Webhook endpoint > Click on event and check the response returned from your server